# Why const void* still be updated in C?

Tags: c

I have some code with `const void*` as below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>    

int main()
{

    const int p = 10;

    char s[] ="I am newbie";

    const void *vp;
    vp = &p;

    *(int*)vp = 11;
    printf("%i\n", *(int*)vp);

    vp= s;
    printf("%s\n", (char*)vp); 

    return 0;
}
```

My question is why `const void* vp` still be updated?
As my understanding, const variable can not be updated directly, is that correct for all types?

Comment: Using an intermediate void pointer makes no difference at all, compared to `*(int *)&p = 11;`

Answer (score 3):

You effectively removed the `const` when you got a pointer to your `int`, cast the *pointer* to something without the `const`, and then changed the value of what *that* points to.

```
*(int*)vp = 11;
```

You can cast a pointer type to any other pointer type.

Modifying a `const` variable like this is undefined behavior. For example, the compiler might have seen that the variable was `const`, realized that it could pre-compute what the `printf` functions would print, and do the substitution at compile time as an optimization. The compiler would be allowed to do this because it thinks the variable is `const`.

Comment: Maybe you should mention about pointer to const too. Anyway, +1 for mentioning about undefined behavior when modifying a const.